# laralvel 5 DB::select returns empty array

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel 5, and inside one of my models, in a relationship, I have the following

```
$fitQuery = $this->getFitQuery();

$results = DB::select($fitQuery);
```

After the execution $results is an empty array. Not null, but with a sizeof() 0.

When I run the query against the database raw, it returns 26 results, and those are expected to be returned on the code above.

The code is correct, since it is a collaborative project, and it works fine on my colleagues end.

I include DB with the full path

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;
```

When I include it with

```
use DB;
```

I get a

> multiple definitions exist for class

warning 
and

> Undefined class: Declaration of referenced class is not found in
>   built-in library and project files

(It auto-finds some declarations outside the project in pear?)

The providers and alliases in app/config.php seem to be ok, in the sense that DB is declared in there.

I am on windows and the above code was written in a Debian enviroment, if it makes any difference. The cloned Debian VM with the project works fine.

I am really lost on this one. Any ideas?

Comment: what are the contents of `getFitQuery`?

Comment: @Filype it constructs the query to be run against the database. It is quite complicated, but it returns a string containing the query.

Comment: @Velix check your queries logs to see what queries you have.
Use it `use DB;` instead of `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;`

Comment: @mcklayin Thanks for your input. After enabling logging, I can see the queries executed, and they are as expected. The fact that they are logged means rhey are executed correctly in the first code snippet I provided right? What could cause the $results array remain empty?